# Como baixar um PDF que está no C:\

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Com o código abaixo eu consigo baixar um JPG, mas com PDF não funciona.
Já tentei alterar a última linha para isso, mas também não funcionou.

`file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/pdf", fileName);`

```
<p:commandButton value="Download do Edital" ajax="false"  >
     <p:fileDownload value="#{fileUploadBean.file}" />
</p:commandButton>

private StreamedContent file;

    public void setFile(StreamedContent file) {
            this.file = file;
        }

    public StreamedContent getFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        String caminho = "c:/tmp/iri.jpg";
        String arquivo = "iri.jpg";
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(caminho);      
        file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, caminho, arquivo);  

      return file;
    }
```

Comment: Veja se pode te ajudar, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265740/how-to-download-a-pdf-from-a-given-url-in-java

Comment: Não funciona por qual motivo? Dá algum erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public StreamedContent getFile() throws FileNotFoundException {

    String arquivo = "iri.jpg";

    String caminho = "C:\\tmp\\"+arquivo;

    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(caminho);      
    file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, caminho, arquivo);  

  return file;
}
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Ver se assim funciona !